# Where is result of OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) obtained from? (typo corrected)

Tags: sql-server, execute-as

I have a stored procedure that has EXECUTE AS another user that has very restricted access.  I cannot get the results from OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) when I run that stored procedure.  @@PROCID does have a value, so it's the lookup that is failing.

I think it's a permissions issue, so can someone tell me where the name of the stored procedure is obtained from?  Maybe I can fix my issue by granting some SELECT permissions to the EXECUTE AS user.

If anyone has any other ideas, LMK.  I'm hardcoding the stored procedure name for now.

Comment: I originally posted this as OBJECT_ID not OBJECT_NAME, so I corrected it in the original question.  Answer references OBJECT_ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [`OBJECT_ID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx):

> A user can only view the metadata of securables that the user owns or on which the user has been granted permission. This means that metadata-emitting, built-in functions such as OBJECT_ID may return NULL if the user does not have any permission on the object.

Also [further reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx) will also tell you that you need to grant the user *any* permission on the object (i.e. SELECT, EXECUTE etc.)

Comment: Your reply did point me to what I needed to do after additional research.  GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO MyExecuteAsUser. [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1593/granting-view-definition-permission-to-a-user-or-role-in-sql-server/)